# Trying to get profile info of the user I get the Error: Captcha is needed (VK Android SDK)

Tags: java, android, api, vk

I use VK Android SDK (com.perm.kate.api) https://bitbucket.org/ruX/android-vk-sdk/overview

The last line of the code i provide below one day began returning KException.

From the documentation:
If some sort of action is completed too often, then the request to API may return the error "Captcha needed". The user will need to enter a code from the image and send the request again with the entered Captcha code in the request parameters:

- captcha_sid - captcha identifier captcha_img
- link to the image thatshould be shown to the user so that they can enter the text from the image.

The question is where should I enter this parameters?
I use the method to get user profile which doesn't contain these arguments:

```
public ArrayList<User> getProfiles(Collection<Long> uids, Collection<String> domains, String fields, String name_case) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, JSONException, KException
```

The code to get a user profile:

```
Api vkApi=new Api(account.access_token, Constants.API_ID);
//get user
Collection<Long>userIds=new ArrayList<Long>();
userIds.add(account.user_id);
ArrayList<User> users=vkApi.getProfiles(userIds, null, null, null); //KException
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set all parameters. Not null but array with empty string, and empty string. My example:

```
Collection<Long> u = new ArrayList<Long>();
u.add(user_id);
Collection<String> d = new ArrayList<String>();
d.add("");

response = vkApi.getProfiles(u, d, "", "", "", "");
```